# Speeding up and understanding Python Keras predict method results analysis

Tags: python-3.x, keras, object-detection, tensorflow2.0, yolo

I'm using Keras and Tensorflow to perform object detection using Yolov3 standard as well as Yolov3-Tiny (about 10x faster).  Everything is working but performance is fairly poor, I'm getting about one frame every 2 seconds on the GPU and one frame every 4 seconds or so on the CPU.  In profiling the code, it turns out the `decode_netout` method is taking a lot of time.  I was generally following [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-yolov3-in-keras/) as an example.

1. Can someone help walk me through what it's doing?
2. Are there alternative methods baked into Tensorflow (or other libraries) that could do these calculations?  I swapped out some custom Python for `tf.image.non_max_suppression` for example and it helped out quite a bit in terms of performance.

```
# https://keras.io/models/model/
yhat = model.predict(image, verbose=0, use_multiprocessing=True)
# define the probability threshold for detected objects
class_threshold = 0.6
boxes = list()
for i in range(len(yhat)):
    # decode the output of the network
    boxes += detect.decode_netout(yhat[i][0], anchors[i], class_threshold, input_h, input_w)
```

```
def decode_netout(netout, anchors, obj_thresh, net_h, net_w):
    grid_h, grid_w = netout.shape[:2]
    nb_box = 3
    netout = netout.reshape((grid_h, grid_w, nb_box, -1))
    boxes = []
    netout[..., :2]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., :2])
    netout[..., 4:]  = _sigmoid(netout[..., 4:])
    netout[..., 5:]  = netout[..., 4][..., np.newaxis] * netout[..., 5:]
    netout[..., 5:] *= netout[..., 5:] > obj_thresh

    for i in range(grid_h*grid_w):
        row = i / grid_w
        col = i % grid_w
        for b in range(nb_box):
            # 4th element is objectness score
            objectness = netout[int(row)][int(col)][b][4]
            if(objectness.all() <= obj_thresh): continue
            # first 4 elements are x, y, w, and h
            x, y, w, h = netout[int(row)][int(col)][b][:4]
            x = (col + x) / grid_w # center position, unit: image width
            y = (row + y) / grid_h # center position, unit: image height
            w = anchors[2 * b + 0] * np.exp(w) / net_w # unit: image width
            h = anchors[2 * b + 1] * np.exp(h) / net_h # unit: image height
            # last elements are class probabilities
            classes = netout[int(row)][col][b][5:]
            box = BoundBox(x-w/2, y-h/2, x+w/2, y+h/2, objectness, classes)
            boxes.append(box)
    return boxes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup with a GPU and have been facing the same problem. I have been working on a YoloV3 Keras project and have been chasing exact issue for past 2 weeks . After finally timeboxing all my functions I found narrowed down the issue to 'def do_nms' which then lead me to the function you have posted above 'def decode_netout'. The issue is that the Non-Max-Suppression is slow.

The solution I found was adjusting this line

```
if(objectness.all() <= obj_thresh): continue
```

to

```
if (objectness <= obj_thresh).all(): continue
```

The performance difference is night and day. I am pushing near 30 FPS and everything is working much better.

Credit goes to this Git issue/solution:

https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo3/issues/177

It took me a while to figure this out, so I hope this helps others.

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed speed things up.  You may also be interested in [this implementation](https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2).  I swapped it out and got pretty good performance.

Comment: I just compared performance, I got about a 30% improvement in performance using the implementation I linked above across CPU and GPU.